# jQuery.load() with sitefinity

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, telerik, sitefinity

I'm going to develop a website which uses ajax to load pages. The cms behind it, is going to be Sitefinity. The problem is I don't know if it's possible to load the pages of sitefinity with jQuery.Load() or any other ajax technique.

Problems with sitefinity:
- I'm able to get the page object of sitefinity, but i need the rendered HTML.
- I'm going to make the pages in the CMS and each page will have a html, header, body tag etc. And I just need the main content of the page, so i'll have to strip the html aswell!

I've been searching alot, but haven't encountered a solution. If someone could give me tips where to search, or how to do it, I'll appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient way to pull the pages in would be to connect to the Sitefinity WCF service with jQuery. You will receive JSON page data via AJAX that you can use to compose your page.

Your project's /Sitefinity/services/ folder is filled with .svc service files that you can query to get various items such as pages (/Sitefinity/services/pages/PagesService.svc/), images, blog posts, etc.

The documentation for using those services from jQuery is a little sparse at this point, but they are actively being improved.

See: [Sitefinity Documentation Calling Sitefinity RESTful WCF services from Client Side](http://www.sitefinity.com/40/help/developers-guide/deep-dive-client-side-programming-restful-wcf-services-in-sitefinity.html)

And [this is a good example](http://wildermuth.com/2010/2/23/WCF_Data_Services_and_jQuery) (non specific to Sitefinity) on how to call WCF services from jQuery.

One note: Sitefinity is very modular and serves pages and content items separately, you may need to query for a page first to find out what content items need to be queried.

Answer (score 0):

Ask on the SiteFinity support forums. The devs are pretty good about answering questions on there.

Comment: they are completely ignoring me :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to retrieve content from Sitefinity via .load(). You can use only a portion of the returned document by doing something like the example below.

```
$('#empty-container').load('sitefinity-page #main-content');
```